# ASP.NET MVC 5 + Owin + Facebook + Amazon ELB + Amazon CloudFront

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am trying to use Owin to authenticate user with Facebook. Eveything is fine, but when I deploy the application on the Amazon EC2 with ELB, behind a CloudFront, the redirect url on Facebook callback is the ELB url, not the CloudFront url.

For Example:

1) I access the site by the CloudFront url and click in Logon: htp://MyCloudFrontDomain/Logon

2) I click on the Facebook logon button and I am redirect to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=123&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FapplicationLoadBalancer...

I am using the folowing code: https://github.com/Code-Inside/Samples/blob/master/2013/OwinKatanaAndOneAspNet/Auth/Controllers/AccountController.cs (see ChallengeResult class)

Anyone have an idea that why the Owin generate the ELB url and not the one that I first access the site (CloudFront url)?